# SVG image embedded in web page doesn't show

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to embed a set of SVG images in a blank web page.

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<img  width="117px" src="img/icone/phone_hex034F84.svg" alt="image">
<img  width="320px" src="img/illustrazioni/SHIPPER3.svg" alt="image">
</body>
</html>
```

Both files are self-contained svg generated by Illustrator.

While the first does render in the browser the second (SHIPPER3.svg) doesn't.

See the code: http://104.155.112.173/land/img/illustrazioni/SHIPPER3.svg

You can download the full source from the previous link as I cannot embed it in the question (too large). Although, I'll embed here just the preamble.

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
 <svg version="1.1" id="_x5B_SHIPPER1_x5D_" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
 y="0px" viewBox="0 0 733.3 587.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 733.3 587.8;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
    .st1{fill:#EDEDED;}
    .st2{fill:#F2F2F2;}
```

If I copy and paste SHIPPER3.svg in http://www.freecodeformat.com/svg-editor.php it does render. I can also open it in Sketch with no problems.

I tried to embed SHIPPER3.svg also as inline svg but same, again, no show.

What I am missing?

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: please post here the  SHIPPER3.svg xml

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: Thank you for comments, I embedded the code.

Comment: Have you tried removing the clipPath node from the generated svg and seeing if that makes a difference? Just from eyeballing it, the clipPath seems to be the most likely culprit.

Comment: If you open the svg file in a browser, and locate one of the `g` nodes then toggle the clip-path attribute off using the browser's DOM inspector, an image appears. So, TL;DR - it's something to do with the clip-path. Inkscape has similar issues. Deleting the clip-path attribute from the group (g) elements causes them to show too - though differently. Each program seems to have slightly different issues with the file. (Chrome & Inkscape)

Comment: @ChrisD - got it in one. ;)

Comment: You are both right. By deleting the whole clipPath tag from the svg XML the image renders correctly. What is the clipPath? Is it safe to delete it completely from the SVG?

Comment: The clip-path was originally used to create an oval vignette effect. If you don't wish to chop parts of the image off that extend outside this (wrongly positioned - too far to the right by about 650 units) oval, then yep- you can nuke the path and references to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems in your `SHIPPER3.svg`:

- all your top-level groups has class `st0` which is said to be clipped out by clipPath that is outside entire `viewBox`
- clipPath `#SVGID_2_` has `style="display:none;"` what also hides it

See:

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 733.3 587.8">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
    /* ... */
</style>
<defs>
    <ellipse id="SVGID_1_" cx="1085.6" cy="279.3" rx="251.8" ry="233.4"/>
</defs>
<clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="display:none;overflow:visible;"/>
</clipPath>
<g class="st0">
 <!-- ... -->
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to a comment I left above, you may wish to replace the `<clippath id='SVGID_2_'` element with the following:

```
<clipPath xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="SVGID_2_">
    <ellipse xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="SVGID_1_" cx="360" cy="290" rx="325" ry="260"/>
</clipPath>
```

This does 2 things. (0) it removes the link to the SVGID_1_ element by inserting the data that was inside it directly. (1) repositions and sizes the ellipse

[image]